# How to send email message only once in ThreadPool executed function?

Tags: python, multithreading, email, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

Here is the function I use to make the API operation 10 times faster:

```
def load_url(req, id, data, timeout):
    headers = {'Authorization': 'AT-API 111111222222333333344444445555555'}
    r = req.post("https://service.com/api/v1/compare", headers=headers, data=data, timeout=timeout)
    data = r.json()
    print id
    if data['error']:
        print data['error']
    else:
        c.execute("UPDATE offers SET valid = ? WHERE id = ?", ('valid' if data['data']['success'] else 'invalid', id))
        print data['data']['success']
        print data['data']['count']
    return r.json()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, s, data['id'], data, 120): data for data in datas}
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
            url = future_to_url[future]
            try:
                data = future.result()
```

We're running this script periodically every 4 hours. In load_url, we print and check the statuses of the request, data['data']['count'] - is an amount of calls remain for a month. I want to send an email notification after we reached 5000 calls or less, but ONLY ONCE. How to implement the sending only one message, but not 5 and not 50? We're using Sqlite3 to store the data.

We're using Mailgun for sending emails:

```
def send_simple_message(email_list):
    for email in email_list:
        response = requests.post(
            "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/newsletter.company.com",
            auth=("api", "key-1234567"),
            data={"from": "Mailgun Sandbox <postmaster@newsletter.mobupps.com>",
                "to": email,
                "subject": "Agent - we reached the limit by API",
                "html": "We reached the limit for agent" })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a lock mechanism to prevent multiple threads from executing the `send_simple_message` function, and set a synchronized value that keeps track of whether the mail has been sent or not.

```
import threading
lock = threading.Lock()
has_been_sent = False

# then in your load_url function you could do something like
if condition on count:
    with lock:
        if not has_beend_sent:
            # send mail
            has_been_sent = True
```

Comment: We're running this script periodically every 4 hours, so we should make sure we remember that it's been sent before.

Comment: and how is it fit in with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor?

Comment: You said you were using sqlite, you could keep track of the last time you sent the mail in a table.

Comment: Have you tried putting the piece of code I gave you into load_url?

Comment: Where would it cause a deadlock? There is a single lock for all the threads.

Comment: Ok, sorry, you're right. I've just read the similar problem with such a solution and thought that here's some risk. Thank you!